# Hive - updating a partition column

Tags: sql, hive, sql-update

I have a Hive table partitioned by date and product type

```
product_id, sale_id, date, product_type
42342423, 43423, 2017-01-01, S 
67867868, 23233, 2017-01-01, C 
53453466, 63423, 2017-02-01, S
```

I need to update all the values of product_type from 'S' to 'T' (Shirts to Tops). A direct update is not possible as our version of Hive does not support it.

Other solutions posted like this involve creating a new table and using `insert overwrite` with `case` statements - something like

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE data.textile_sales PARTITION(date='2017-01-01')
select product_id, sale_id, case when product_type = 'S' then 'T' end as product_type, date
```

but this wouldn't work if the column to be updated is a partition.

Is there any other method to go about this?

Comment: P.s. `case when product_type = 'S' then 'T' end as product_type` - this expression will result in NULL for product_type which is not 'S'

Answer (score 0):

The partition columns "data" is actually a metadata related to the directories.
If you already have 'T' folders then move the files from their current date + product_type='S' folders to the corresponding date + product_type='T' folders.
If you don't have 'T' folders, you can simply rename the 'S' folders and update the partitions list.

---

Demo

```
hive> select * from product;
OK
67867868    23233   2017-01-01  C
42342423    43423   2017-01-01  S
53453466    63423   2017-01-02  S
```

---

```
[training@localhost ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls -R /user/hive/warehouse/product
drwxrwxrwx   - training hive          0 2017-01-10 13:35 /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-01
drwxrwxrwx   - training hive          0 2017-01-10 13:36 /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-01/product_type=C
-rwxrwxrwx   1 training hive         15 2017-01-10 13:36 /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-01/product_type=C/000000_0
drwxrwxrwx   - training hive          0 2017-01-10 13:35 /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-01/product_type=S
-rwxrwxrwx   1 training hive         15 2017-01-10 13:35 /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-01/product_type=S/000000_0
drwxrwxrwx   - training hive          0 2017-01-10 13:36 /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-02
drwxrwxrwx   - training hive          0 2017-01-10 13:36 /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-02/product_type=S
-rwxrwxrwx   1 training hive         15 2017-01-10 13:36 /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-02/product_type=S/000000_0
```

---

```
[training@localhost ~]$ hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-01/product_type=T
[training@localhost ~]$ hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-02/product_type=T
[training@localhost ~]$ hdfs dfs -mv /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-01/product_type=S/000000_0 /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-01/product_type=T/000000_0
[training@localhost ~]$ hdfs dfs -mv /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-02/product_type=S/000000_0 /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-02/product_type=T/000000_0
```

---

```
[training@localhost ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls -R /user/hive/warehouse/product
drwxrwxrwx   - training hive          0 2017-01-10 13:41 /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-01
drwxrwxrwx   - training hive          0 2017-01-10 13:36 /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-01/product_type=C
-rwxrwxrwx   1 training hive         15 2017-01-10 13:36 /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-01/product_type=C/000000_0
drwxrwxrwx   - training hive          0 2017-01-10 13:42 /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-01/product_type=S
drwxrwxrwx   - training hive          0 2017-01-10 13:42 /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-01/product_type=T
-rwxrwxrwx   1 training hive         15 2017-01-10 13:35 /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-01/product_type=T/000000_0
drwxrwxrwx   - training hive          0 2017-01-10 13:41 /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-02
drwxrwxrwx   - training hive          0 2017-01-10 13:42 /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-02/product_type=S
drwxrwxrwx   - training hive          0 2017-01-10 13:42 /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-02/product_type=T
-rwxrwxrwx   1 training hive         15 2017-01-10 13:36 /user/hive/warehouse/product/date=2017-01-02/product_type=T/000000_0
```

---

```
hive> msck repair table product;
OK
Partitions not in metastore:    product:date=2017-01-01/product_type=T  product:date=2017-01-02/product_type=T
Repair: Added partition to metastore product:date=2017-01-01/product_type=T
Repair: Added partition to metastore product:date=2017-01-02/product_type=T
Time taken: 0.409 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

---

```
hive> select * from product;
OK
67867868    23233   2017-01-01  C
42342423    43423   2017-01-01  T
53453466    63423   2017-01-02  T
```

Comment: Are you still there?

Comment: I didn't have access to change the data files so I ended up reloading the affected data with the new values